# Python Flask - webbrowser doesn't work properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, pythonanywhere

I've written a small Flask app that runs on a pythonanywhere.com Server.
If I test my application locally everything works fine, but when I do on the pythonanywhere Server my webbrowser function doesn't work.
Little Explanation what this one Site does: I have one tab where an User can upload files to the server. The files are saved in a seperate folder. Then theres another tab in my app where you can see all files in that folder (os.listdir) and an entry box where you can write a file name in and when you press submit it will automatically download it to your PC.

[Little Download Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEgzr.png)

Code for my Upload tab, the overview of the files and last but not least the actual downloader:

```
@app.route('/upload.html',methods = ['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def upload():
    if request.method =='POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename))
            flash("File uploaded succesfully: ")
            flash(filename)
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploads.html', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def uploads():
    flash(os.listdir('/Users/julian/pyytest'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        vdatei = request.form['datei']
        if request.form['datei'] == '':
            flash('Feld darf nicht leer sein')
        else:
            webbrowser.open("http://localhost:5000/uploads/%s"
                            % vdatei)

    return render_template('uploads.html')



@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
@login_required
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```

Summary: Everything works fine locally and when I deploy my app on pythonanywhere webbrowser.open() wont open the site to download the file in my server.
I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I'd imagine that port 5000 might be closed on their server

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Comment: Actually, are you sure that the url should be **localhost**? In fact I'm not even sure if `webbrowser.open` can work properly if called from a remote machine. A [redirect](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors) would be a more logical approach IMO (more in keeping with web practices). This should also fix the potential port issue.

Comment: Yeah the URL is localhost because this is my local script. There will be a different Link obviously when I deploy my App to pythonanywhere.

Comment: That was the point I was trying to make - hardcoding the address of the server is not a good practice and using redirects is a better approach.

Comment: How should I implement the redirect? I've tried:
redirect(url_for("http://localhost:5000/uploads/%s"
                            % vdatei))
and redirect("http://localhost:5000/uploads/%s"
                            % vdatei)
First approach gives me an Internal Server error and second method does literally nothing.

Comment: loose the *localhost* bit: `return redirect(url_for("uploads/%s" %vdatei))` should work

Comment: Apparently it doesn't.. "Internal Server Error" :/

Comment: Wouldn't it be logical if I put return redirect(url_for("uploaded_file(vdatei))) in there? But that won't work as well..

Comment: oh right, sorry I got a bit confused there, I now found the correct [docs for `url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#url-building) - your last code is nearly correct. `return redirect(url_for("uploaded_file", filename=vdatei))`

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time, it finally worked. I know I'm still a newbie :p